# Getting image format in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written this code. I want to upload 2 images in asp.net C# program (image and Gif). I accept image when it's JPG format.

Would you please tell me how to do so?

I read all topic similar to my problem! please don't refer me to them!:)

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase image , HttpPostedFileBase Gif)
{
    Image i = Image.FromFile("image.FileName");

    if (System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(i.RawFormat))
    {
        string imageName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
        string image_path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + imageName);
        image.SaveAs(image_path);

        ViewBag.image_path = image_path;
    }

    string gifName = Path.GetFileName(Gif.FileName);
    string gif_path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + gifName);
    Gif.SaveAs(gif_path);

    ViewBag.gif_path = gif_path;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: I get 2 files. one image in JPG format and another if Gif. I dont write that section about Gif condition @marc_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Path.GetExtension();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that purpose. like

```
if(Path.GetExtension(image.FileName) == ".jpg")
{
  //do your work
}
```

Change your code a bit like

```
if (image != null && Path.GetExtension(image.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpeg") 
{ 
   string imageName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName); 
   string image_path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), imageName); 
   image.SaveAs(image_path); 
   ViewBag.image_path = image_path; 
}
```

Comment: I changed my code to this but my problem is not resolved. my files are not uploaded in image folder
 `if (Path.GetExtension(image.FileName) == ".jpg")
            {
                string imageName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
                string image_path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + imageName);
                image.SaveAs(image_path);
                ViewBag.image_path = image_path;
            }`@Rahul

Comment: See edit in answer if it helps.

Comment: thanks! Good answer, but when I debug it "imageName" is null ! and doesn't allow program to save my file in image folder @Rahul

Comment: post your calling code. Want to see what you are passing.

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
            
            <p>Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) </p>
            <p>Image:</p><input type="file" name="image" id="image"/>
            <p>Gif:</p><input type="file" name="Gif" id="Gif" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        }`

Comment: thank you!!!! when I debug with Chrome it worked well! sorry ..:)